# How long after sending a header('Location: ...') command will the PHP script process?

Tags: php, redirect, header, include

I have two PHP scripts which both have an "include_once('authentication.inc');" script near the top.  Both scripts reference the same authentication file.  That authentication file currently performs a header redirect (like "header('Location: index.php');") if the user is not signed in.

In one file (A.php) the immediate next line of code after the include of the authentication file is:

```
if(isset($_GET['delete']))
   mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE index=".$_GET['delete']);
```

In the other file (B.php) there are several other includes which occur before the same "delete code" listed above.

So the authenticate.inc file looks like:

```
if(!valid_credentials($username,$password))
    header('Location: index.php');
```

And file A.php looks like:

```
include_once('authenticate.inc');

if(isset($_GET['delete']))
   mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE index=".$_GET['delete']);
```

And file B.php looks like:

```
include_once('authenticate.inc');

include_once('other.php');
include_once('file2.php');
include_once('onemore.php');

if(isset($_GET['delete']))
   mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE index=".$_GET['delete']);
```

Yet when I call A.php?delete=5, that record is deleted from the database while when I call B.php?delete=8 that record is not.

I have checked the 3 intermediary includes and do not see any die() statements, nor any other header redirects.

So while it's clear that A.php is continuing to execute after the header is sent, why isn't B.php doing the same thing?  Is the header being sent before the next set of imports?

**

### Also: I know to add the die() or exit command after the headers are sent. I'm working on someone else's code and trying to explain behavior, not writing this myself.

**

Comment: /!\ Be careful when using $_GET or $_POST datas in sql queries: [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: I think the first step in debugging, if possible, is to try commenting out your includes and see if the delete executes.  If it does, start adding your includes one by one to see which is killing your script.  The only thing different between those two files seems to be those includes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No way to tell. If the starts are aligned properly, the header coud be sent to the client browser immediately and the bowser will start closing the current connection and request the new URL immediately. This'll cause the current PHP script to start shutting down.

On the other hand, if the caches are slow and the network glitchy, the client browser may not get the redirect header for seconds/minutes/hours, and the script could continue executing indefinitely.

In general you should assume that the moment you've issued a header redirect that the script is basically "walking dead" and should not do any further work.

The sole exception to this rule is that you CAN use `ignore_user_abort(TRUE)`, which tells PHP to **NOT** shut down when the remote user disconnects. That'd allow you to continue on working even though the browser has shut down the connection and moved on to the new page.

Comment: Best answer I saw, thanks.  I guess I didn't understand the nature of the header request: that PHP is essentially telling the client to quit it's current request and start a new one, which depends upon the connection speed between their server and my client.  As you said: impossible to tell [for an unknown client].

I was assuming PHP was telling ITSELF "stop sending this page!  send this NEW one instead!" but it appears that's not the case at all.

Comment: I had the same feeling but - a rare thing - some nice person bringed me over.

Comment: nope. a "Location: ..." header basically gets PHP to issue a 302 redirect, which tells the remote client. "Hey, you should go over ... for this content". Whether the remote client actually obeys that is out of PHP's hands.

Comment: @myingling you are wrong. Apart from the fact that a client can do ANYTHING at they will, if they follow the protocol recommendations, the PHP is telling quite contrary - not to quit immediately but to wait until request is over. At least for the POST requests but it seems all modern browsers do wait for the GET to finish as well

Comment: @myingling as for the PHP talking to itself - you come to right conclusion. There is a thing called "HTTP" and it can reveal you many interesting things.

Comment: @Marc B Yeah, that makes sense... don't know what I was thinking there.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Aside from the insulting comment about HTTP, if your first statement were accurate, then these scripts would behave the same.  That they don't indicates there's some sort of processing time between them making a difference.

Comment: @myingling LOL, there is also a thing called "logic". it can tell you that you cannot conclude such things :) in fact, there can be thousands of reasons for these scripts to not behave the same. And HTTP protocol is even more insulting as it says `the entity of the response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the new URI(s).` - so, a client should wait for this. you can also do a test, it is not that hard: add sleep(5) after calling header and see if you willbe redirected immediately

Answer (score 2):

Update your authenticate.inc file to `die()` after the redirect.  This will prevent any other code from executing.

```
if(!valid_credentials($username,$password)) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}
```

Without it, and depending upon your server configuration, the rest of the PHP code will be executed on the server even after the headers are transmitted back to the client.  Until the client closes the connection, the code will run.

Comment: Was just going to say this as well. Can't stress the importance of this enough.

Comment: I know, that's why I put this as the last line of my question: Also: I know to add the die() or exit command after the headers are sent. I'm working on someone else's code and trying to explain behavior, not writing this myself.

Answer (score 1):

Just put an exit() after the header redirect.  It will stop all execution after the redirect.

Comment: I know, that's why I put this as the last line of my question:

Also: I know to add the die() or exit command after the headers are sent. I'm working on someone else's code and trying to explain behavior, not writing this myself.

Comment: Oh, didn't read that. I actually thought the same as you, and thought it would stop executing after the headers are sent, so thanks, good question.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably some output in either of the included files, with `echo` or other outputting functions. If the browser by then has followed the redirect and aborted the connection, the PHP script will by default exit. You can change this behaviour with `ignore_user_abort(true);`. You should however use `die();` after the `Location` header. If the query execution is wanted, just put that query before the `Location` header. Don't forget to use proper escaping for the input, otherwise the script could be a target for a mysql injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, it seems that the browser will wait until your script finished execution and only then will request another location.

Please note that you shouldn't use GET method to delete records.

As for the not deleting id=8 - just debug it. Not a big deal.
A good var_dump() is always better than some vague ideas about headers.